# Does "precipitation" have anything to do with "precipitous"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, origin-unknown

**precipitation**

1. the action or process of precipitating a substance from a solution.
2. rain, snow, sleet, or hail that falls to the ground.
3. archaic,the fact or quality of acting suddenly and rashly

It's a synonymous of drop I think;

While **precipitous**

1. dangerously high or steep:
2. (of an action) done suddenly and without careful consideration:

synonyms: steep · sheer · perpendicular · abrupt · sharp · vertical

Both give me a sense of abruptly and related to the "altitude", "vertical".
So, it's of pure coincidence or they have something to do with each other? Say coming from a same root? Tried but found nothing related, So I thought I'd post. Apologies if it contains grammar mistakes and wrong use of words. Feel free to edit it.

Comment: *Ceps* is from Latin *caput* "head"; *pre* is from Latin *prae*, which in this context means something like "forward", so *praeceps* is something like "head first". Both English words are from *praeceps* ultimately.

Comment: The avalanche started with rocks tumbling from the precipice, precipitously raining down on us, like a hard and granular precipitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the etymology is the same ***praecipitare***:

[precipitous](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Precipitous&searchmode=none) (adj.)

> - 1640s, "rash, headlong," from obsolete French precipiteux (16c.), from Vulgar Latin *praecipitosus, from praecipitare (see precipitation).

[precipitation](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=precipitation&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.):

> - late 15c., "a casting down" (of the evil angels from heaven), also, in alchemy "separation of a solid substance from a solution," from Middle French precipitation (15c.) and directly from Latin praecipitationem (nominative praecipitatio) "act or fact of falling headlong, haste," ***noun of action from past participle stem of praecipitare "fall, be hasty,"*** from praeceps "steep" (see precipice). Meaning "sudden haste" is c. 1500. Meaning "act of falling from a height" is attested from 1610s. Meteorological sense of "rain, snow, dew, etc." is from 1670s.

(Etymonline)